# Odoo 10 ORM API - Create seller ids for ProductTemplate

Tags: odoo

I have

```
_seller_ids = [(0, 0, {'min_qty': 1.0, 'product_code': u'1006004', 'price': 1.0, 'name': res.partner(84,)})]
```

and

```
my_product_template = ProductTemplate(34,)
```

How can I create those seller_ids -in the example it is just one supplier but it might be more than that as it is a list- for my_product_template? - ProductTemplate(34,)-

I have tried:

```
my_product_template.seller_ids.create(_seller_ids)
```

without success

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below:

```
my_product_template.seller_ids = [(0, 0 , {'min_qty': 1.0, 'product_code': u'1006004', 'price': 1.0, 'name': seller.name}) for seller in sellers]
```